# Facing some issue when trying to start Solr in cmd

Tags: solr, sitecore, solr-search

Have a nice day!

I want to start solr to install Sitecore. I'm unable to install solr in my system. When I try to install solr. It shows some error. Please assist me to solve this issue.......

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu2Ji.png)
Thanks,
Akash M

Comment: Is there start.jar in the folder called server?